# Get route path from name in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1

Well I know that `route('some.route.name')` returns the url for a route based on its name. Is there any way to get a path instead of the url?

I can subtract(or better say str_replace) `route('my.website.root.route.name')` from it, but I was just wondering if there was a way to do it in a straight forward fashion.

Thanks =)

Comment: There are others functions that can do the same things such as `action` or `url`, but I suppose that each one returns a url. Have I focused the question?

Comment: As a matter of fact they both return a url as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use controller to make links .. and you can use in view with {{ }}

on controller.. add like,

```
 public function index() {
    $weburl = asset('http://www.google.com/sample/pic/');
    $myurl = asset('/mysite/data/sample/');

    $data= array(
                    'weburl' => $weburl,
                    'myurl' => $myurl,
                );

    return View('index', $data);
}
```

then you can call this links on view using double curly brackets

```
{{ $weburl }} or {{ $myurl }}
```

Guess this way is easier to use..

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not gonna do what I want. The whole point of what I want is so that if the url changed, I wouldn't have to change them anywhere else. Just in the route definition.

Comment: yeah bro.. you can get same with this... you just need to change path in controller file .. it will change link wherever it is defined!!

Comment: Yes you're right. Thank you. I'll just change your code a little bit to clarify it. Thanks again.